# Python code is working without error but not making directory or saving files in some computers

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have written this code below. It is working very well in my computer and lots of other ones. But recently someone told me that it is not working in his computer. No errors occur but it doesn't create files.
Can someone tell me what I should do?

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
import os
import shutil 

image_address = sys.argv[1]

im = Image.open(image_address + '.jpg') 

try:
    os.mkdir(image_address)

except:
    shutil.rmtree(image_address)
    os.mkdir(image_address)

im.crop((76, 232, 1887, 1439)).save(image_address + '/' + image_address + '-01.jpg')
im.crop((88, 1518, 1886, 2680)).save(image_address + '/' + image_address + '-02.jpg')
im.crop((84, 2882, 1899, 4129)).save(image_address + '/' + image_address + '-03.jpg') 
im.crop((88, 4233, 1896, 5437)).save(image_address + '/' + image_address + '-04.jpg')
im.crop((88, 5548, 1896, 6751)).save(image_address + '/' + image_address + '-05.jpg')
im.crop((80, 6828, 1896, 8038)).save(image_address + '/' + image_address + '-06.jpg')
im.crop((39, 8062, 1919, 9227)).save(image_address + '/' + image_address + '-07.jpg')
im.crop((75, 9280, 1917, 10505)).save(image_address + '/' + image_address + '-08.jpg')
im.crop((71, 10611, 1915, 11839)).save(image_address + '/' + image_address + '-09.jpg')
im.crop((71, 11933, 1915, 13162)).save(image_address + '/' + image_address + '-10.jpg')
im.crop((72, 13257, 1915, 14486)).save(image_address + '/' + image_address + '-11.jpg')
im.crop((72, 15898, 1923, 17130)).save(image_address + '/' + image_address + '-12.jpg')
```

Comment: Don't worry about it ;-)

Comment: Has he/she checked the right folder? Has he/she provided a path as expected from your sys.argv[1]? Maybe that person used a blank, then the files should be in the folder where the python script is.

Comment: How does he run it? Maybe it runs in a way that doesn't show error messages (e. g. with "pythonw" under Windows) although they are there. Maybe a separate error logging mechanism is necessary.

Comment: He is doing the same as i do.  No such things that you mentioned occured